# Views relationship from nid to gid

Tags: nodes, organic-groups, views

I currently have a content type that is keyed by its organic group's gid, but I am trying to make a contextual filter based on nid. Is there is relationship to get the gid from the nid directly?

I could write a relationship to do that, but would that be a difficult task to do?

edit: gid is the group id of the organic group.

Comment: Would you expand what gid is?

Comment: Ok, I see you've tagged the question with organic-groups so I think gid is the group id.